# How to screen capture a second desktop in Mac Mojave?

Tags: macos, command-line, screen-capture

If I call `screencapture -R460,250,350,500 ~/Desktop/screenshot.png` from the command line, is there an option or way to tell it to take a screenshot of Desktop 2, rather than Desktop 1?

Comment: According to `man screencapture`, the -D option should capture or record from the display specified (1 - main display, 2 - secondary, and so on.)  Example: **screencapture -D2 -R460,250,350,500 ~/Desktop/screenshot.png** should capture from the second display. Unfortunately _it doesn't work_!

Comment: Confirmed -D2 appears not to work, even when both displays are using the same Space. -R[location + width of 1st monitor] works to capture the right-hand screen, but not another Space.